# Looking for a novel about an expansion in the Earth's landmass - Possibly "Cataclysm"

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I remember a novel about the Earth's landmass going from roughly a third of the total surface area to almost a half so that mankind had more room. I thought it was called "Cataclysm" and would have been written sometime in the 70's I believe. Trying to find the author's name and the official title.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=cataclysm&type=Fiction+Titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the 1969 novel [Cataclysm: The Day the World Died](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/116904.Cataclysm)  by Don Pendleton?  The publication date would be about right. The story does include shifting landmasses e.g. with the ever popular California sliding into the ocean. I don't remember much else though I was reading this about the time I was the Mack Boland Executioner series so quite some time ago.

More info in the summary [here.](http://trashmenace.blogspot.com/2015/11/cataclysm-by-don-pendleton.html)

Comment: THAT'S IT! Thank you, thank you, thank you. I also was reading a lot of the Executioner series then, too, so it makes sense. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you could please mark the answer as accepted that would be appreciated.  Thanks.